# How to handle synchronization in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a script that writes multiple data to db and middleware that save Answer object reference in Question object:

```
AnswerSchema.post("save", async function(doc) {
    if (this.isThisDocNew) {
        const question = await Question.findById(doc.question);
        question.answers.push(doc._id);
        console.log(question._id, question.answerCount);
        question.answerCount += 1;
        await question.save();
    }
});
```

This is the output:

```
5e302a02685d0667c54d42ea 0
...
5e302a02685d0667c54d42ea 0
```

I expect answerCount 2 but the result is 1. How can I handle this problem?

edit Quesion Schema:

```
const QuestionSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please, provide a title"],
        minlength: [10, "Please, provide a title with minimum 10 chars"],
        unique: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please, provide content"],
        minlength: [20, "Please, provide content with minimum 20 chars"],
    },
    slug: {
        type: String
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "User"
    },
    likes: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }],
    likeCount: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    answers: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "Answer"
    }],
    answerCount: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you add the schema for `Question`?

Comment: I added QuestionScema.

Comment: Hm this works fine for me with the provided schema - are you sure above code is actually executed? Is `this.isThisDocNew` true?

Comment: Yes, if it doss not executed, console.log can not called.

Comment: You are updating `answers` but expect `answerCount` to change, why?

Comment: I also update answerCount: question.answerCount += 1; here. But if two requests come, answerCount is both zero at that time. Requests do not wait each other to update question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

```
AnswerSchema.post("save", async function(doc) {
    if (this.isThisDocNew) {
        await Question.findByIdAndUpdate(doc.question, {
            $push: {
                "answers": doc._id
            },
            $inc: {
                "answerCount": 1
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Now, when multiple requests come, they will wait until the anwerCount updated.